# How to create Javascript to search Google

Tags: javascript, automation, sahi

I am using Sahi for automation and just as a little experiment of what I can do in JavaScript ( I am fairly new to JavaScript)

I want to create an automation process that will search through Google until it finds my website to see where it is listed for certain words (I understand this is fairly pointless but just want to experiment)

This is what I have written so far, but I don't want to write _click(_link("2")) _click(_link("3")); every time and want the java to go to the next page until it finds a page with my website on.

How would I use a loop, (while loop) to increment the page numbers and repeat that step until it finds  page that matches the title of my page?

```
_setValue(_textbox("q"), "phillip marsden design");
_click(_submit("btnG"));

if (_condition(_exists(_link("PJM | Portfolio"))))
{
                _click(_link("PJM | Portfolio"));
}
else
{
                _click(_link("2"));
}
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Java is to Javascript like car is to carpet

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not off-topic since I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

You could look at the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) which allows you to return data in JSON format, which in turn you could parse them with, for example, [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: I am not trying to find out where my page lists, nor do I care I just want to know how I can use the while loop, or other increment system. So it's not that I want to work with Google, more about my understanding of Javascript and its possibilities with Sahi